# Why does my Vanilla JS Calculator's number change at the 17th digit?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, project, calculator

It's a basic calculator made by the youtube channel Web Dev Simplified.
He did a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j59qQ7YWLxw) on it, which I followed along and basically made the same thing.

Both his example calculator and mine has the same problem,
where if I pressed on any of the number buttons (for example '1') 17 or more times, the numbers entered after the 16th digit displays as a different number for some reason (17th digit becomes '2' and not '1').

It does this with any number entered. I don't understand why.

I attached a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/LyuHiroyama/pen/MWQBbEQ) so that you can see both his code and the code output.

You will find the display output in this part of the HTML code:

```
  <div class="output">
  <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
  <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: because the Max safe integer .... [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and what on earth has that huge calculation LOL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because your number is over than integer
add console.log() in the `getDisplayNumber` function and Compare the log and the display data

in the log, it looks like `1.1111111111111111e+21` when out of the range

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

```
getDisplayNumber(number) {
const stringNumber = number.toString()
const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
console.log(integerDigits)
let integerDisplay
if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
  integerDisplay = ''
} else {
  integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
}
if (decimalDigits != null) {
  return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
} else {
  return integerDisplay
}   }
```